Eventbridge pattern for SSM document
I want to make sure that my lambda triggers only when a particular ssm document status is Success, so i have written the following eventbridge pattern but it is not working.
I want to make sure that my lambda triggers only when a particular ssm document status is Success, so i have written the following eventbridge pattern but it is not working.
"source": ["aws.ssm"],
"detail-type": ["EC2 Command Status-change Notification"],
"detail": {
    "documentName": ["MyDocument"],
    "status": ["Success"]

But when i remove the document name it is properly triggering my lambda, i would like to know how could we make sure that only if this particular document is success it has to trigger my lambda.

It seems there is a typo in the document's name key.
It has to be "document-name" instead of "documentName".
Can you try the following:
{
 "source": ["aws.ssm"],
 "detail-type": ["EC2 Command Status-change Notification"],
 "detail": {
           "document-name": ["MyDocument"],
           "status": ["Success"]
           }
}

Sample event taken from AWS EventBridge:
{
"version": "0",
"id": "51c0891d-0e34-45b1-83d6-95db273d1602",
"detail-type": "EC2 Command Status-change Notification",
"source": "aws.ssm",
"account": "123456789012",
"time": "2016-07-10T21:51:32Z",
"region": "us-east-1",
"resources": ["arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-abcd1111",
"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/i-abcd2222"],
  "detail": {
    "command-id": "e8d3c0e4-71f7-4491-898f-c9b35bee5f3b",
    "document-name": "AWS-RunPowerShellScript", // Key name to fix in your pattern
    "expire-after": "2016-07-14T22:01:30.049Z",
    "parameters": {
      "executionTimeout": ["3600"],
      "commands": ["date"]
    },
    "requested-date-time": "2016-07-10T21:51:30.049Z",
    "status": "Success"
  }
}

